# Google App Engine files on Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

How can I get following variables in Google App Engine Cloud Storage using php:--

1. number of files in specific bucket
2. number of files with specific extension in specific bucket

Comment: Although there are many people on SO that can help you, no one will provide a from-scratch solution. Post what you have tried and follow-up on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) on GCS, e.g. glob("gs:///*.txt"). However, it may not be the most efficient solution if there is a large number of files.